# How resolve a dependency with unity passing arguments in the constructor?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, unity-container

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I pass constructor parameters to Unity’s Resolve() method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787001/can-i-pass-constructor-parameters-to-unitys-resolve-method)
>   [Constructor Injection in C#/Unity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2015308/constructor-injection-in-c-unity)

It is possible to resolve a dependency with unity passing arguments in the constructor of the service to resolve ?

If it is how I can do it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create an `InjectionConstructor` and pass that to `RegisterType()`:

```
var unityContainer = new UnityContainer();

ISnuh snuh = new Snuh();
InjectionConstructor injectionConstructor = new InjectionConstructor(snuh);

unityContainer.RegisterType<ICalculator, SimpleCalculator>(injectionConstructor);
```

If you have to do it only when you resolve the type, that's when `ResolverOverride[]` would be used:

```
public static T Resolve<T>(this IUnityContainer container, params ResolverOverride[] overrides);
```

Per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660920%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx):

> Use ParameterOverride to override the specified constructor parameter
>   or parameters.

Comment: This is the only place you will simplified syntax for constructor.