# OAuth: ASP.NET Web API User.Identity doesn't load claims set by authentication token provider

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api, oauth, castle-windsor, claims-based-identity

I am using OAuth bearer authentication, configured like this in Startup.cs:

```
        OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions oAuthBearerOptions = 
            new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AccessTokenProvider = new AccessTokenProvider(),
                AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active
            };
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(oAuthBearerOptions);
```

... where AccessTokenProvider is implemented as:

```
public class AccessTokenProvider : AuthenticationTokenProvider
{
    public override async Task ReceiveAsync(AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext context)
    {
        // Internal logic to get data needed for building identity...

        // Create claims identity
        ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(identityName);
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, nameIdentifier));
        // Add other claims

        // Set claims identity
        context.SetTicket(new AuthenticationTicket(identity, new AuthenticationProperties()));
    }
}
```

If I set a breakpoint at the end of `ReceiveAsync`, I can verify that the identity is built correctly (has claims) and that `SetTicket` is reached.

But when I try to access the identity from a Web API controller:

```
public abstract class BaseStorageController : ApiController
{
    protected IStorageService StorageService;

    protected BaseStorageController(IStorageServiceFactory storageServiceFactory)
    {
        StorageService = storageServiceFactory.CreateStorageService(User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity);
    }
```

}

... the list of claims on the identity is empty!

What can be causing this?

Side note: I don't know if this is related, but I am using Castle Windsor as an IOC container to inject dependencies into my controllers (in the above case, IStorageServiceFactory). The above seemed to work (claims were not empty) before I added that. However, I'm not using CW to manage anything related to authentication. Here is my CW installer for api controllers:

```
public class ApiControllerInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly().BasedOn<ApiController>().LifestylePerWebRequest());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer. It was not related to dependency injection/inversion of control. I'm not sure how I thought it was working prior to adding that.

The issue is similar to what is described here (but in my case the solution is different): [User (IPrincipal) not avaliable on ApiController's constructor using Web Api 2.1 and Owin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23785528/user-iprincipal-not-avaliable-on-apicontrollers-constructor-using-web-api-2-1)

Basically `IPrincipal` is not accessible from the constructor of the api controller, which is why there are no claims (the user is not yet authenticated). `User.Identity` is only accessible from the controller's actions, not the constructor. I changed my base controller implementation to the following to get around this issue:

```
public abstract class BaseStorageController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IStorageServiceFactory _storageServiceFactory;
    private IStorageService _storageService;

    protected BaseStorageController(IStorageServiceFactory storageServiceFactory)
    {
        _storageServiceFactory = storageServiceFactory;
    }

    protected IStorageService StorageService
    {
        get
        {
            if (_storageService == null)
            {
                _storageService = _storageServiceFactory.CreateStorageService(User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity);
            }
            return _storageService;
        }
    }
}
```

Since `StorageService` is only accessed from controller actions, `User.Identity` is authenticated and has claims populated by the time that the `StorageService` getter gets called.

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Thanks!!! I had the constructor issue going on all day and tried multiple different authprovider implementations. This solved it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected IStorageService StorageService
{
    get
    {
        if (_storageService == null)
        {
            _storageService = _storageServiceFactory.CreateStorageService(User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity);
        }
        return _storageService;
    }
}
```

this is not the best approach for implementing DI

It's much better to use constructor injection. 
Check [Constructor Injection in C#/Unity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2015308/constructor-injection-in-c-unity)
if you are not familliar with Unity, follow this link, very useful:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn223671(v=pandp.30).aspx

Regards

Comment: The IPrincipal is not available in the constructor of a web api controller which means constructor injection doesn't work in this case.